# Modify Clonezilla boot parameters on generated images/ISOs

Tags: boot, clonezilla

I *can* take a Clonezilla-generated ISO and extract the contents, then manually edit the syslinux.cfg (and other .cfg's) to adjust the boot parameters after creating the ISO, then repackaging it up. However, I'd like to be able to have these boot parameters be changed *while* creating the images instead of having to throw in several extra steps (*that I don't want the customer doing in the first place*). Ideally this can be done by modifying the source Clonezilla image so that it would automatically append to the default boot parameters.

I had hoped that Clonezilla would take it's own modified boot parameters (via cfg files, not manually typed in) and simply carry them forward to the child ISOs, but alas, it does not.

Edit: Bonus points for also changing the .png file that it uses for the background. It doesn't carry that over from parent to child either.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs that it is not necessary to unpack the ISO images at all to either alter or remove/add contents; you can merely use a suitable archive managing tool (such as 7zip) to view and alter the contents before making suitable copies of the ISO as desired.

As for the background image - it exists as a 640*480 in `syslinux/ocswp.png` - replacing this with another .png of equal dimensions will alter the background image on boot.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue of not having the customer have to open up the ISO and manually edit the files. They may be computer illiterate. I'd sooner just give them something to type in manually at the boot screen, but I'm trying to create a smooth process with little risk of user fault.

Comment: It may be a good idea to go back to your original post and edit it for clarity then; it is not currently particularly clear what your setup is - you have only really listed what is not possible rather than precisely what you wish to achieve and the environment in which you seek to achieve it. eg, who is 'the customer' in your scenario?